# How do I manage AWS spot instances in a way that is cost efficient?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spot-instances

I am new to AWS and still getting the hang of coding with the API they provide.
What I'm essentially doing right now is to launch a spot instance and connect provisioned volume, and whenever a 2-minute termination notice arrives, launch a new spot instance and attach that volume while canceling the previous spot request.
My concern for this method is whether this is cost-efficient, or am I just wasting more money by attaching provisioned volume? If anyone has a better way of managing their spot instances with fault-free method I would be grateful if you could share some thoughts.

Comment: What do you store on that volume? Can you store the data on S3 instead, so you don't need to keep reconnecting that volume?

Comment: That would be the more logical thing to do, right? Since you would need to pay for the size of the volume created while s3 only requires you to pay for the amount that you take out. Then, would you say that detaching and attaching a provisioned volume is not very ideal?

Comment: Attaching and detaching a volume is not a good approach, since it's dealing with AWS and Operating systems. Much simpler to store data in S3, which is accessible from any instance without having to perform any attach/detach operations. Worst case, you could use utilities like s3f3 or MountainDuck to 'mount' S3 as a volume (but I don't like to recommend that for Production use).

Comment: I see, thank you for the helpful comment. It would seem that using Provisioned IOPS as separate storage would cost even more money for the spaces that I don't use as well as adding input/output operations bills.

Comment: If you are purely focussed on lowering costs (which I guess is why you are using a Spot instance), then S3 would be a better option than Amazon EBS storage, yes. That's why I was asking what you store on the volume, and how you use it, to see whether S3 would be a viable option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.